# List with a dynamic dictionary, present the key and value separately (using variables)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to present the key and value of a dictionary which is constantly changing, now what I go through the algorithm I see what it does not. It only works for the first item

```py
[
  {
    'author name': 'Amy Berke',
    'author link': None
  },
  {
    'author name': 'Robert Bleil',
    'author link': None
  },
  {
    'author name': 'Jordan Cofer',
    'author link': None
  },
  {
    'author name': 'Doug Davis',
    'author link': None
  }
]
```

This code is only presented by the first author

```py
Dictionary = [{'author name': 'Amy Berke', 'author link': None}, {'author name': 'Robert Bleil', 'author link': None}, {'author name': 'Jordan Cofer ',' author link ': None}, {' author name ':' Doug Davis', 'author link': None}]
keysInternas = dictionary [0] .keys ()
index = 0
for keyInterna in keysInternas:
  internalValue = dictionary [index] [internalInternal]
  print (internalInternal, ":", internalValue)
  index + = 1
```

Sometimes I have

```py
[
  {
    'author name': 'Amy Berke'
  },
  {
    'author name': 'Robert Bleil'
  },
  {
    'author name': 'Jordan Cofer'
  }
]
```

or also

```py
[
   {
     'author name': 'Amy Berke',
     'author link': None,
     'image link': None
   },
   {
     'author name': 'Robert Bleil'
     'author link': None,
     'image link': None,
   }
]
```

But the code just introduces me

```py
author name: Amy Berke
author link: None
```

With the code that I have at the moment only the first element presents me why it is not useful for me in any case. I want to present the key and value of each element

PS: I can't alternate much the format comes from a bigger dictionary

Comment: Hello! At the moment, it's hard to tell what you're asking. Could you elaborate on what the expected and actual behavior of you code is? Are you simply trying to print the contents of a list of dictionaries?

Comment: The sample code you provided has a lot of problems. Please fix them, so we can test what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewQ I try to use the same code to present key, value regardless of the structure, and I put that code because I don't know how to do it ... but because I would put it

Comment: @Brian the idea is that regardless of how the structure is presented, showing key and value is essential, I keep both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the data you are passing is not a dictionary it is a list. In order to print out each author separately, you must loop through the list of authors (dictionaries). Then you loop through the author's details. If you want to print out the key and the value of each field, then the best is to call the `items` method, it returns a list of tupled keys and values (example: `[(key1, value1), (key2, value2), ...]`). Each item will be a tuple. Then you use the `print` function and print out a formatted string. The `format` method excepts multiple parameters, so you would need to pass each element of the item separately, but you can use the `*` operator to unpack the item (it means to pass each element as a separate parameter).

```
this_is_not_a_dictionary_but_a_list = [{'author name': 'Amy Berke', 'author link': None}, {'author name': 'Robert Bleil', 'author link': None}, {'author name': 'Jordan Cofer ',' author link ': None}, {' author name ':' Doug Davis', 'author link': None}]
for dictionary in this_is_not_a_dictionary_but_a_list:
    for item in dictionary.items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(*item))
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification I had my doubts (that happened when you skip the basics I guess), could you help me getting key and value separately (in variables) I have to store the

Comment: forget it hehehe the essential is important when I have time I check [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Going to assume you don't want to do anything fancy like store the author in `json` or `yaml` format (although I would highly recommend doing that).

If you want to take your dictionaries as is and display each value and make sure you grab each new value inside each item (assuming you don't want to go another level deep in your information), you could try something like this:

```py
a = [
  {
    'author name': 'Amy Berke'
  },
  {
    'author name': 'Robert Bleil'
  },
  {
    'author name': 'Jordan Cofer'
  }
]

b = [
   {
     'author name': 'Amy Berke',
     'author link': None,
     'image link': None,
   },
   {
     'author name': 'Robert Bleil',
     'author link': None,
     'image link': None, 
    }
    ]

for author_package in a:
    for key in author_package:
        print(f'{key}: {author_package[key]}')

for author_package in b:
    for key in author_package:
        print(f'{key}: {author_package[key]}')
```

Which would give you the output:

```
author name: Amy Berke
author name: Robert Bleil
author name: Jordan Cofer

author name: Amy Berke
author link: None
image link: None
author name: Robert Bleil
author link: None
image link: None
```

This works because you can grab every item (as an `iterable`) within the dictionary and then grab every key (again an `iterable`) that is contained the key that you just grabbed.

Maybe take a look as storing things in `json` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp or yaml if you are planning on storing the files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was told to store the key and value separately ... although to be sure I ask tomorrow. In any case the code would have to work for any structure because I don't know what data I analyze (I suppose that by saving them separately a way to classify them, in the future I guess ... or who knows)